# Difference between openssl base64 and javascript's btoa

Tags: openssl, base64

I have different results when I try to encode a string to base64 by using openssl or javascript's btoa function (the last character is different).

```
# From a bash terminal on Ubuntu
echo 'admin:passw0rd' | openssl base64
# returns YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQK

# From Chrome's javascript console
btoa('admin:passw0rd')
# returns YWRtaW46cGFzc3cwcmQ=
```

Online base64 encoding services seem to give the same result as `btoa`. The algorithm is easy and the password does not contain any special character. So what can explain this difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just tested, and I confirm your findings:

MAC Terminal / command line:

```
$ echo 'admin:passw0rd' | openssl base64
YWRtaW46cGFzc3cwcmQK
$ echo 'admin:passw0rd' | base64
YWRtaW46cGFzc3cwcmQK
```

Console

```
window.btoa("admin:passw0rd")
"YWRtaW46cGFzc3cwcmQ="
```

BUT, when you change your command to:

```
$ echo -n 'admin:passw0rd' | base64
YWRtaW46cGFzc3cwcmQ=
```

It gives the same result. By default, echo will add a newline character to the string, so you are piping that to the base64 command to. By adding -n it will not do that. From the man pages:

```
-n    Do not print the trailing newline character.  This may also be achieved by appending `\c' to the end of the string,
       as is done by iBCS2 compatible systems.  Note that this option as well as the effect of `\c' are implementation-
       defined in IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 (``POSIX.1'') as amended by Cor. 1-2002.  Applications aiming for maximum portabil-
       ity are strongly encouraged to use printf(1) to suppress the newline character.
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's better to use `printf "%s" "$data"` rather than `echo -n "$data"`, just in case `$data` is something like `-e` which echo will process as another option argument.

Answer (score 2):

The `echo` add a newline to the openssl command.

You should use option `-n` (no newline) with the echo command:

```
echo -n 'admin:passw0rd' | openssl base64
YWRtaW46cGFzc3cwcmQ=
```